# What is a scan: {} block in Java?

Tags: java

I was looking at the source code for the class String for [8u40-b25 JDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.toUpperCase%28java.util.Locale%29), and it contains a `scan: {}` block:

```
2557        /* Now check if there are any characters that need to be changed. */
2558        scan: {
2559            for (firstUpper = 0 ; firstUpper < len; ) {
2560                char c = value[firstUpper];
2561                if ((c >= Character.MIN_HIGH_SURROGATE)
2562                        && (c <= Character.MAX_HIGH_SURROGATE)) {
2563                    int supplChar = codePointAt(firstUpper);
2564                    if (supplChar != Character.toLowerCase(supplChar)) {
2565                        break scan;
2566                    }
2567                    firstUpper += Character.charCount(supplChar);
2568                } else {
2569                    if (c != Character.toLowerCase(c)) {
2570                        break scan;
2571                    }
2572                    firstUpper++;
2573                }
2574            }
2575            return this;
2576        }
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Jon nailed it. But on first reading, I thought it was a keyword too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scan` is just a label. It allow this later on:

```
break scan;
```

... to allow the `break` statement to break out of the outer loop instead of the inner loop.

See [section 14.7 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) for more details of labeled statements.